# JSON data not Valid?

Tags: json, httprequest

this is the JSON data I send

{"installer":"inno_ext_bundle","installer_version":"1.0.0.0","event_type":"init","sessionid":"4EE24CB5-8C45-4B92-9BA2-EBB4A8A4F0E3"}

for some reason JSONLint says I have an error 
can anybody help here?

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: does that not suggest adding an opening brace to the front of **WinHttpReq**? Have you tried that